# Get if "Display this list on the Quick Launch?” is checked using SharePoint WebServices

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am working on Sharepoint Version 2007. I want to know the "Display this list on the Quick Launch". I have to use SharePoint web services. There is a **flags** attribute. Is there any way to retrieve it from flags.

Could anyone help me out please?

Thanks